# Need help showing $T(ax^2+bx+c)= ax^2-(a-2b+2c)x+3c$

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem had a few parts that I attempted to work out.  The problem states let $T:P_2\to P_2$ be the linear transformation satisfying:  $$T(x^2-1)=x^2+x-3,\\T(2x)=4x,\\T(3x^2+2)=2(x+3)$$.

Find $T(1)$, $T(x)$, and $T(x^2)$, and hence, show that $T(ax^2+bx+c)=ax^2-(a-2b+2c)x+3c$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are arbitrary constants.

My work:

Find $T(x)$:

$T(2x)=4x$$\quad\Rightarrow$$\quad2T(x)=4x$$\quad\Rightarrow$$\quad T(x)=2x$

Find $T(1)$:

$T(x^2-1)=x^2+x-3$$\quad\Rightarrow$$\quad T(x^2)-T(1)=x^2+x+3$$\quad\Rightarrow$$\quad T(x^2)=x^2+x+3+T(1)$

I move to the next equation to isolate $T(x^2)$:

$T(3x^2+2)=2x+6$$\quad\Rightarrow$$\quad T(3x^2)+T(2)=2x+6$$\quad\Rightarrow$$\quad 3T(x^2)+2T(1)=2x+6$$\quad\Rightarrow\quad 3T(x^2)=2x+6-2T(1)$$\quad\Rightarrow\quad T(x^2)=\frac{2x+6-2T(1)}{3}$

I set the two previous results equal to each other to find $T(1)$, which I found to be $\frac{-3x^2-x+15}{5}$.   I plugged this into $T(x^2) = x^2+x-3+T(1)$ which resulted in $T(x^2)=\frac{2x^2+4x}{5}$.

I feel like I've done something wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your work is flawless. Well done. Can you solve part two?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't look like the RHS...particularly because there aren't any fractions. Or does that matter?

Comment: There is a mistake in question. In order to get $$T(ax^2+bx+c)=ax^2-(a-2b+2c)x+3c$$The last equation should be $T(3\color{red}{x}+2)=2(x+3)$, not $T(3\color{red}{x^2}+2)=2(x+3)$.

Comment: I guess that would explain it. I double-checked the problem to make sure I saw it correctly. I guess the text will be revised for that error!!